# jquery error on start up

Tags: jquery

When I load my page that uses jquery, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
jQuery.jQuery.fn.jQuery.ready test.html:282
(anonymous function) test.html:15
jQuery.jQuery.extend.ready
```

This is tracked down to

```
ready: function( fn ) {
    // Attach the listeners
    jQuery.bindReady();

    // If the DOM is already ready
    if ( jQuery.isReady ) {
        // Execute the function immediately
        fn.call( document, jQuery );
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    // Otherwise, remember the function for later
    } else if ( readyList ) {
        // Add the function to the wait list
        readyList.push( fn );
    }
```

fn above is undefined... There is no other symptom I can see that points me to the problem. I am referencing a local copy of jquery.js.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Using the google cdn does not help either.. Cant imagine I'm the first person hitting this...

Anyone with pointers to help a newbie?

thanks in advance,
Jas

Comment: Post the source code of your html page, including all scripts you are executing. Are you using another JS library besides jQuery?

Comment: where and how you define the fn function passed as fn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is it you're trying to initialize? generally anything that needs to be done on a page ready is done like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //your JS calls, functions, bindings, and whatever


});
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `ready` is itself called without an argument (or with one that is `undefined`).

Comment: Thanks for the really quick and helpful advice. So Ii figured out where the problem is. Still not sure why it is happening... he situation is this:

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you have code somewhere in your page equivalent to:

```
$(document).ready(undefined);
```

You need to pass a function reference to the ready() method, as shown in FatherStorm's reply. If you are passing in a function name, ensure that the function is available in the scope that you are making the call to ready(). If you are defining the function inline, check for syntax problems or other errors on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

In my case, I removed one of my custom validator `jQuery.validator.addMethod()`,
But I forgot to remove it from rules.

```
$("##frmCreate").validate({
    rules: {
        zip: {required: true, maxlength: 6, postalcode:true},
```

In above case, postalcode was my custom validator.

Hope it can help others..